# function which returns a random value of 1 or 0

Tags: c

```
int random_var(void);

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
        printf("%d\n", random_var());

return 0;
}


int random_var(void)
{
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    return rand() % 2;
}
```

I am tasked to write a function that returns a random value of 1 or 0 everytime it is called. My code keeps returning a fixed value even though I used a random generator for the seed, why??

Comment: You could just `return !rand();`. Nobody said anything about the relative likelihood of 1 and 0.

Comment: @EOF: You could just `return 0;`. Nobody said anything about the relative likelihood of 1 and 0.

Comment: @KeithThompson I presume you'll be relying on the occasional cosmic ray flipping a bit to supply the required randomness?

Comment: @EOF: No, 0 is just as random as any other number. 8-)}

Comment: @KeithThompson: Randomness is not a property of a single number but of a sequence. The sequence containing only zeros is considerably non-random.

Comment: @EOF If you didn't like Keith's joke, you won't like http://xkcd.com/221/ either.

Comment: @SteveSummit: I like it just fine. I am just currently in a pedantic mood.

Comment: @EOF: You're trying to out-pedant ***me***?  8-)}

Comment: @KeithThompson To the best of my ability, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `srand()` only once!

```
int random_var(void);

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    for (i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
        printf("%d\n", random_var());

    return 0;
}


int random_var(void)
{
    return rand() % 2;
}
```

Alternatively (or additionally), as **Keith Thompson** pointed out, you can try taking higher order bits instead, which may distribute better.

Comment: *Some* implementations of `rand()` will return alternating even and odd numbers. [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com} question 13.18.

Comment: @KeithThompson, I'd upvote your comment if I hadn't have reached the daily limit today. However, sadly, [some popular implementations won't...](https://ideone.com/ajAD1Y)

Comment: Of course if you re-seed with the same value you'll get the same results.

Comment: To expand on the problem, the OP is calling `srand` which seeded with the time in seconds. The tight `for` loop from 1 to 50 will execute in much less than a second, so `srand` is getting seeded with the same value 50 times. Therefore `rand()` will return the same value 50 times. If you happen to execute this loop during the transition to then next second, `rand` would return a different number, then the new one would be repeated until the loop terminated.

Comment: @yano, you should post that as an answer. It's spot on.

Comment: heh, thought about it, but it would've been the same as your answer .. think it's all covered now